# Regularly Update Client Side UI on Progress of Server Side Task

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly application. One of the server side methods, which is called after a button is clicked on the UI, creates a number of database records but for various reasons this process can take up to a minute. During this time, the UI isn't providing any feedback to the user until the task is fully completed.

Is it possible with Blazor WebAssembly for this task to be running whilst the client side sends regular requests to the server to get data on the progress of the task (which I can get via SQL).

If this was a console or WinForms application. I'd probably split the main task and the progress updates into two separate threads but I'm unsure if this is the right way to do it with Blazor WebAssembly. If multithreading isn't possible here, is there an alternative way to achieve this desired functionality in Blazor WebAssembly?

Comment: We have implemented a notification system using SignalR so we send a message to the queue and once that task is completed, it lets the client know about the task, have a look at SignalR integration with Blazor WebAssembly.